# Dynamic due date with ACF Pro for Elementor Pro

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, advanced-custom-fields, elementor, acfpro

I have a function to add a dynamic due date to the Countdown Timer widget from Elementor (Pro). With ACF Pro I created a options page with a date and time picker to change the date, but it doesn't work and I cannot see why. I also tried other codes from [this page](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/7737), but they also don't work. I get a timer with 0 days, hours, minutes and seconds or with the date entered via the Elementor edit page.

Here's the code:

```
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/widget/before_render', function(\Elementor\Element_Base $element){
    if ("countdown"  != $element->get_name()) return;
    
    $countdown_date = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "my-date-field",true);

    $element->set_settings("due_date",date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($countdown_date))) ;

});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you named the **Field Name** is **"my-date-field"** and the **Field Type** is **"Date Time Picker"**(look at below image for more detail).
[image]

If this is not fix your issue then:
Do you get any error message on **WP Dashboard** or **Debug console**?

**Update:**

After take a look on your backend and make some debug, i found that you set your custom field is in option page, while this piece of code use to get the value of the custom field base on the post's ID.

To get this value, you will need a different code like this:

```
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/widget/before_render', function(\Elementor\Element_Base $element){
if ("countdown"  != $element->get_name()) return;
$countdown_date = get_field('my-date-field', 'option', false);
$element->set_settings("due_date",date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($countdown_date)));
});
```

Also, please make sure that you set the correct return format to **"y-m-d H:i:s"** for the code working as below image:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I entered the field name correctly. Nor the dashboard as the debug console are showing any errors. If I add the code to my functions.php, the only change is that the clock only shows 00 00 00 00. I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please follow the instruction so i can debug and fix the issue for you.

Comment: I updated the code, [this](https://imgur.com/3RxGYWt) is the result from frontend.

Comment: Seem to be the problem come from the **get_post_meta()** function. Please modify your function as my new update and show me the result again!

Comment: Thanks for you help! Here's the [result](https://imgur.com/Aj9fedQ).

Comment: I have updated my solution, please take a look!

Comment: Hi I changed the code but unfortunately it still doesn't work. See [this](https://imgur.com/HoxnbGp) screenshot of the settings in ACF. I see 00 00 00 00 in date and time. Perhaps the ACF field is not setup well? And [this](https://imgur.com/WNhbXAf) is what I have in Elementor.

Comment: I have test this on my site, and it work perfect. Maybe there is conflict with other plugin. If you don't mind, please give me a temporary access to your dashboard, i will debug and fix this for you!

Comment: Yes please, too where can I sent you the login credentials?

Comment: Please send it to windprince18@gmail.com

Comment: This answer resolved my case. Thanks a lot for all the help Thống. As not mentioned in the code above, I changed `strtotime($countdown_date)` to `strtotime($countdown_date.'+2 hour')` to add 2 hours because my timezone is different. It was set up correctly in Wordpress, but due to a limitation in ACF Pro, this was the only solution and was also provided by Thống. Thanks again! 5 stars!